# why this Producer-consumer demo crashed？

Tags: c++, multithreading

I try to write a producer-consumer demo with c++11 but a tricky problem happend.Here is the Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
std::condition_variable pcv,ccv;
std::mutex m,m1;
const int N=10;
int buf[N];
int count=0;
void producer(){
    Sleep(100);
    while(true){
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> pulk(m);
        while(count==N)
            pcv.wait(pulk);
        buf[count++]=1;
        cout<<"produce data on the buff: "<<count<<endl;
        while(count==1)   //if I remove this no problem
            ccv.notify_one();
        pulk.unlock();
    }
}
void consumer(){
    while(true){
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> culk(m);
        while(count==0)
            ccv.wait(culk);
        buf[--count]=0;
        cout<<"consume data on the buff: "<<count<<endl;
        while(count==N-1)   //if I remove no problem
            pcv.notify_one();
        culk.unlock();
    }
}
int main(int argc,char **argv){
    std::thread  pro(producer);
    std::thread  con(consumer);
    pro.join();
    con.join();
    return 0;
```

the program will run the next line forever

```
while(count==1)  //if the buffer empty?
    ccv.notify_one()
```

I try to use GDB find this reason but no result
Here is the GDB output 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The lines `while(count==1) //if I remove this no problem` and `while(count==N-1) //if I remove no problem` make your synchronization fragile. You consider only two states of ten (N) possible.